# Android multiple custom resource files using qualifiers

Tags: android, directory, locale, android-resources, qualifiers

I have an app where I want to change the text according to a specific property or an option that the user selects. The text is not in another language so I can't use the standard resource qualifiers like `values-en`, `values-nl` etc. and switch to it by changing the locale.

In short when user presses "button A" I would like to use values-a/strings.xml and when user presses "button A" I would like to use values-b/strings.xml. However when I try to do this I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid resource directory name
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How you're getting these values? I mean some java code.

Comment: @eleven: well I don't have any code yet, because this error occurs at compile-time whenever I add the folder values-a/strings.xml. But I think the code would be the same as switching to another Locale by updateConfiguration().